# IMPORTING XML FROM SERVER using CRON on presta cPanel

Tags: cron, wget

Im trying to set up CRON task to import from this url https://www.vapefully.com/pl/feed-b2b/ to my server.

I used this code on Cpanel

> ```
> wget "https://www.vapefully.com/pl/feed-b2b/" --output-document=vapefully.xml
> ```

But in result i got this almost empty file

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SHOP> </SHOP>
```

This is what i get from CRON

```
> --2019-12-21 12:25:02--  https://www.vapefully.com/pl/feed-b2b/
Resolving www.vapefully.com (www.vapefully.com)... 35.242.195.100
Connecting to www.vapefully.com (www.vapefully.com)|35.242.195.100|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://vapefully.com/pl/feed-b2b/ [following]
--2019-12-21 12:25:02--  https://vapefully.com/pl/feed-b2b/
Resolving vapefully.com (vapefully.com)... 35.242.195.100
Connecting to vapefully.com (vapefully.com)|35.242.195.100|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [application/xml]
Saving to: ‘vapefully.xml’

     0K                                                        6.69M=0s
    2019-12-21 12:25:02 (6.69 MB/s) -      ‘vapefully.xml’     saved [65]
```

> 

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that when your cron runned, the xml was filled?
Try to call simply from browser the link, and if the xml is filled with the product, try to run the crone, and compare the result.
(I think that when the cron ran, the xml didn't contain the products, only "shop> SHOP>")